# Does BTRFS support the ioctl(fd, FIFREEZE) system call?

Tags: btrfs, system-calls, ioctl

the manpage of *fsfreeze* states:

> ```
> FSFREEZE(8)              System Administration            FSFREEZE(8)                                             
>                                                                                                                                                                                             
> NAME                                                                                                                                                                                           
>        fsfreeze - suspend access to a filesystem (Ext3/4, ReiserFS, JFS, XFS)
> ```

Which leaves me puzzled with regards if BTRFS is not suppported for fsfreeze and neither for the underlying system call:

```
ioctl(fd, FIFREEZE)
```

Answer (score 1):

The same manual* later on [emphasis mine]:

> FILESYSTEM SUPPORT
> This command will work only if filesystem supports has support for freezing.  List of these filesystems include (2016-12-18) **btrfs**, ext2/3/4,  f2fs,  jfs,  nilfs2, reiserfs,  and  xfs. Previous  list  may be incomplete, as more filesystems get support.  If in doubt easiest way to know if a filesystem has support is create a small loopback mount and test freezing it.

<sup>*Specifically: `man 8 fsfreeze` on Debian GNU/Linux 10 with util-linux 2.33.1-0.1.</sup>